# show results from user city

Tags: php, cookies, geolocation

I would like to show the results from `DB` by visited user `city`, I have 2 ideas to do it.

- First ask the user on First Visit to website to pick there Location using `javascript` popup and store it in cookie for further visit.
- Second option is to user the `IP to Location` APIs to get the current user location automatically and store a cookie using php.

I am not sure which one will be best, second option is not `100%` accurate since the IP to Location can give you some wrong result.

Guys please suggest what way you would go? what data should I store in cookie?

**any free API which you prefer to get the current city of user.**

Comment: You can use html5 Using HTML Geolocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods, including the ones you've indicated.  It's a good idea to implement multiple methods to get the most accurate results.

In a project we recently completed, we attempted to detect the user's location, and displayed that information to them in the header of the site, giving the user the option to click and change it so they can supply the correct location if our detection was inaccurate.  We implemented the following methods:

- [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).  This information is provided by the user's
  browser, however it also will prompt the user to ask them if they
  want to submit this information (at least, it does in Firefox, I don't
  recall how other browsers behaved).
- [PHP GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php).  This one is server-side, and will usually give
  results accurate to a city, but not always.  Particularly if the user
  is using a mobile hotspot, it may detect them on the other side of
  the country.
- If we couldn't make any detection, accurate or otherwise, we would
  prompt the user for this information (this particular application was
  dependent on this information, so there was no ability to proceed
  without knowing this).

Comment: thanks for explanation, thats what i thought I have to deal it with fallback methods. if user does't have GeoLocation support in browser we will prompt for Manual city selection

Answer (score 0):

I would suggestion a combination of two options.

First, use the IP geolocation API such as IPInfoDB.com to detect the location of IP address.

Next, provide the information to users and request them to update if the location is wrong.

In this case, you will always get the location of users.